# How can I find if an arbitrary process is running under wow64?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need a tool which will discover whether an arbitrary process is running in x86 or x64 mode on a machine.  I need to do this programatically from C++, based on a process ID.

There has to be some way to do this (as you can clearly see it from the task manager).  Does anyone know of a windows api that will tell you, given a process ID, whether the application is running under wow64?

Another approach would be to figure out, based on the process id, the executable name/path that is running and try to read the PE headers out of the file.  Does anyone have a code snippet that would accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a WinAPI function, [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: +1. Note that you need a handle to the process to use this function, and as a result it's likely you'll need administrative privies, and you'll need to take the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege.